# Embedded SVG is trimmed

Tags: image, html, svg

I embedded an SVG object in an HTML page as follows:

```
<embed id="svgImg" src="bo5rkbgs5vtsmv053regld2t14.svg"
 type="image/svg+xml" />
```

However, the resulting image (both on Firefox and Chrome) is trimmed and it look like that:

[image]

(Notice how "Step Response" and "Time" do not appear properly). I have checked the file on the server side and it is fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks to me like the image size is not large enough for the image itself. Do you have any CSS or other HTML code for us to see to double check with?

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose No, I don't have any CSS associated with the page. The SVG image should appear in natural size according to my code.

Comment: Do you have a link to a live site I can see?

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose Yes, you can find it at https://77.70.17.3/vlab/ - Click "Run" for the image to appear.

Comment: Well your SVG image does have a height:

`<svg width="576" height="432" viewBox="0 0 576 432" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">`

Try removing that or increasng it.

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose Ok... I reduced a bit the height and now at least the title of the figure appears properly. But the problem remains with the label of the x-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tweak your viewBox attribute so that it fits your image.

For example, you could try this:

```
viewBox="-10 -10 596 452"
```

**Update:**
To generate the viewBox dynamically with JS, something like this should work:

```
var bbox = document.documentElement.getBBox();
var viewbox = document.documentElement.viewBox.baseVal;
viewbox.x = bbox.x;
viewbox.y = bbox.y;
viewbox.width = bbox.width;
viewbox.height = bbox.height;
```

Note that this needs to be done on the svg document, so you may need to reach into it from the html document that embeds it, if so have a look at this [example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/get-embedded-svg-document-script.html).

Comment: I tried it (manually) and it works. The problem is how to tell Octave (which creates my figures) to change the viewBox. Is there a way to change it using JS?

Comment: Yes, that's possible, I'll update the answer with a JS solution. The software that generated the file should ideally be fixed so that it doesn't generate such content. Another way is to preprocess the files using SVG Scour, http://www.codedread.com/scour/.

Answer (score 2):

Having had a second look at your code your svg image is still too small.

You need to set the height to 100% and the image height to 500px.

```
<embed id="svgImg" height="100%" type="image/svg+xml" src="s1d5ckv8bojltpturlonh1uap5.svg">
<svg width="576" height="500" viewBox="0 0 576 432" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

....

This fixes the problem in firefox v8.0

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem for me on Firefox 3.6.24 (Ubuntu version). However with height:70% it appears fine (but yet not perfect). The title appears fine but the x-label is again trimmed.

Comment: Try increasing the height a bit more. Set it to 1000px and see if that helps, if it does then its just a case of finding a height that works in all browsers.